# make temporary socket

Tags: sockets, integration-testing, uniqueidentifier

Some of our integration tests need to bind a service to a socket.  This often conflicts with an actual service (e.g. a web service, or another instance of the test... using the same socket)

We have got utilities to create unique temporary files, but is there something equivalent to create system-wide unique sockets?

Comment: If you don't bind explicitly to a particular port number, systems assigns an ephemeral port number on its own. You can then query the port assigned. Is it what you need?

Comment: Sounds about what I need.